Whats generating Android build message having upgraded Kotlin 2.0.0 Kapt currently doesn't support language version 2.0+. Falling back to 1.9
I have migrated my android application to kotlin 2.0.0 and replaced kapt with ksp for dagger.
however when i build my application i get the following build warning message:-
> Task :common:persistence:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
w: Kapt currently doesn't support language version 2.0+. Falling back to 1.9.

i have searched my entire application source code in android studio and cannot find a single mention of kapt.
why am i still seeing this warning?

I had the same error, turned out i still had the plugin

kotlin-kapt

in the

build.gradle.kts(:app)

Removed now the error has gone.
